# all certs and provision work done, iTunes connect configured but still getting error

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode4.2

wwdr cert
developer cert
distribution cert

developer provision
distribution provision

app id

devices

itunes connect

after all that i modified a bundle identifier in info.plist that i have in itunes connect
then archived project and through organizer i try to verify i am getting

No suitable application records were found.
Please make sure that you have set up a record for this application on iTunes Connect.

how to resolve this issue how to get exactly where the problem is?

i am using xcode 4.2 ios 5 os x lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "iTunes Connect configured", what do you mean?

You need to have created an app, entered the description and it needs to be in the "Ready up upload" state. If it's not, Xcode won't see it.

Comment: current status = Prepare for Upload

Comment: The current status needs to be Ready for Upload. When you click on your Application in iTunes Connect, there should be a grey button on the top right which says Ready to Upload

Comment: 2 mins i am uploading the screenshots

Comment: sorry i m having prob uploading the image but there is no grey button which says ready to upload.....the top right blue button ready to upload binary

Comment: when i clicked on this button its a Export Compliance page and asking 
Is your product designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? yes or no .........

Comment: So... you're not in the Ready to Upload state. You need to upload some images and press the "ready to upload" button before you can send your binary to Apple using Xcode.

Comment: "when i clicked on this button its a Export Compliance page" Yes. You need to answer these questions before you can upload. This is all covered in the iTC guide.

Comment: You need to upload some images?? i already uploaded the iTunes icon screen shots metadata etc...

Comment: The screenshots and icon are the images I was referring to.

Comment: now its talking about application loader ... whats this app? if its going to upload my app then why verify archive in organizer ... i am new to this process thats why asking many questions.

Comment: Application Loader is the old way. You can use Xcode. As noted above, this process is covered in the iTC guide.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the version is also set to the version number you have in iTunes Connect